# How to parse a dynamically loading wildberries page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I need to extract data from a comment block that is loaded dynamically. I have tried many methods from the Internet, all of them return an empty array.
The program cannot access the comments because they are loaded only when the user scrolls through the page to them. How can I get all the content of the page?
Page - https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/22063490/detail.aspx?targetUrl=XS
Here is the code that I have now.

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import lxml

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
safe_delay = 15

def read_comments(url):
    response = req.get(url)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(safe_delay)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
    #soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
    coms = soup.find_all('div', class_='comment j-b-comment')
    return(coms)

print(read_comments('https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/22063490/detail.aspx?targetUrl=XS'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to scroll down the page for the comments to load.  You can do this by sending the `space` key repeatedly, with a small `sleep` value to give the page time to load.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/22063490/detail.aspx?targetUrl=XS'


    
def read_comments(url):
    driver.get(url)
    
    for x in range(10):
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(.5)

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
    coms = soup.find_all('div', class_='comment j-b-comment')
    return coms
```

Comment: Jesus, man, you saved my life from dying at the hands of deadline. I will remember you all my life, you are invited to my wedding and funeral.

Comment: Drink a beer for me the next time you get a chance :P  Nobody should suffer from missing a deadline!  Cheers.